# Ошибки перевода на странице 404

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На странице [удалённого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458972/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) есть такие ошибки:

[image: страница 404]

1. Опечатка "поелезны" вместо "полезны".
2. Текст гласит "Чтобы узнать возможные причины удаления вашего вопроса", хотя это не мой вопрос. На [английской странице](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314769/where-i-can-get-mac-os-x-app-installers) написано "possible explanations why a question might be removed", т.е. нет указания на принадлежность ко мне.

Ну и раз уж мы здесь, по смыслу текст ссылки должен указывать на объект, т.е. вместо

> [Чтобы узнать возможные причины удаления вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions), обратитесь в Справочный центр.

должно быть

> Чтобы узнать [возможные причины удаления вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions), обратитесь в Справочный центр.

(опять же см. [английскую страницу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314769/where-i-can-get-mac-os-x-app-installers)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большое спасибо за замечания! Поправил. В ближайшее время строки будут доступны на сайте.